# Finding the series and remainder

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I could find the numbers in the series to be 0,1,4,13,40......
Using the method of differences I could find the nth term to be $\left(3^{n}-1\right)/2$. But, how to find the remainder? Putting n=2010 would result in a very large number so, I believe there is some simplification to be done to find the answer easily. Please give me some hints on doing the same.

Comment: You can compute the remainder of $3^{2010}$ modulo $11$ without computing $3^{2010}$. Note that if $3^a = r_a + 11\cdot k_a$ and $3^b = r_b + 11\cdot k_b$, then $3^{a+b} = r_ar_b + 11\cdot (\text{whatever})$, and you can reduce $r_ar_b$ modulo $11$.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know modular arithmetic.

Comment: Then I think now is a good time to learn it. For problems of this kind, it's more or less necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$3^2=9\equiv-2\pmod {11}, 3^3\equiv5,3^4\equiv 4,3^5\equiv1$

In fact, $3^5=1+11\cdot22$

$\implies 3^{2010}= (3^5)^{420}=(1+11\cdot22)^{420}\equiv1\pmod{22}=1+22b$(say) where $b$ is some integer

$\implies \frac{ 3^{2010}-1}2=11b\equiv0\pmod{11} $

---

Without using Modular Arithmetic,

As $3^5=1+11\cdot22,$   $\displaystyle \implies3^{2010}=\left(3^5\right)^{420}=\left(1+22\cdot11\right)^{420}$

$\implies 3^{2010}=1+\binom{420}122\cdot11+\binom {420}2(22\cdot11)^2+\cdots+\binom {420}{420-1}(22\cdot11)^{420-1}+(22\cdot11)^{420}$ so each term except the first is divisible by $22$

So, we write $3^{2010}=1+22c$ where $c$ is a positive integer

$\displaystyle \implies  \frac{ 3^{2010}-1}2=11c$ which is divisible by $11,$ hence the required remainder will be $=?$

Comment: Sir, as you are from India I would like to tell you that this question had come in KVPY examination. Do they also ask on all these high level mathematics?

Comment: Sir, please reply because the exam(KVPY-2013) is near and I have to prepare well.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, This is for the first time, I have heard' KVPY'. This is not the best forum to ask such question, either. My question is: could you follow my method? You can see the knowledge of Binomial Theorem will suffice to understand the proof

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, added an alternative method using Binomial Theorem

Comment: that was a nice method sir.....

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, my pleasure. But, please don't avoid modular arithmetic which is really nice